# A triangle has sides x, x+4, and 3x−5. What is the possible range of x?

Tags: triangles, geometric-inequalities

> A triangle has sides $x, x+4,$ $and$ $3x−5$. What is the possible range of x?

The answer to this is not:

> $2x-9$ $<$ $x$ $<$ $4x-1$

Which is gotten from:

--> $(3x-5)-(x+4)<x<3x-5+x+4$

--> $3x-5-x-4 < x < 4x-1$

--> $5x-9 < x < 4x-1$

So what is the answer?

The correct answer has to be in:

> __ < x < __

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $y = x$, $y = x  + 4$, and $y = 3x - 5$? Also, could you explain how you came to the non-answer you've given us?

Comment: @TheoBendit I fixed it

Comment: $b-a<c<a+b$ is just bringing up $2$ out of $3$ inequalities. You forgot $b+c>a$. Just write the 3 sides and write all 3 inequalities, and solve them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Consider using the triangle inequality

> $$a+b>c$$

Thus you have that $$x+(x+4)>3x-5\iff 9>x\tag{1}$$
$$x+(3x-5)>x+4\iff 3x>9\iff x>3$$ Hence

> $$x\in(3, 9)\text{ or equivalently }\color{red}{3<x<9}$$

Comment: Yes, b-a<c<a+b?

Comment: shouldn't this be b-a<c<a+b

Comment: So they are interchangeable?

Comment: Which inequalities were used here? a+b>c and what?

Comment: No are, b−a<c<a+b and b−a<c<a+b interchangeable?

Comment: @BeastCoder2 I just used the inequality $a+b>c$ twice changing the sides

Comment: If they are interchangeable, why can't we do --> $(x+4)+(3x-5) > x$ --> $4x - 1 > x$ --> $x > 1/3$?

Comment: @BeastCoder2, Of course, you could use $$(x+4)+(3x-5)>x\implies 4x-1>x\implies x>\frac{1}{3}$$ Observe however that the lower bound $x>3$ is much tighter, so $x>1/3$ in't necessary

Comment: Last question I promise :) the answering website says that $1/3$ is wrong but three is right, how would I know to instantly find the lower bound that is the tightest?

Comment: I would simply try all three permutations of the triangle inequality, i.e. $$\begin{array}a a+b>c \\ c+a>b \\ b+c>a \end{array}$$ Observe the consequences of these simple inequalities and decide which bound (upper and lower) is the tightest. In this particular case, you obtained with the inequalities that $$x>\frac{1}{3}\quad x>3\quad x<9$$ Which of them are the tightest?

Comment: Oh, I get it thank you!